# concatenating batch of files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, concatenation, batch-processing, cat

I'm using Ubuntu OS. I have a folder with files named:

```
part-r-00000_dep1.csv
part-r-00000_dep1.csv
part-r-00000_dep1.csv
.
.
.
part-r-000799_dep1.csv
```

I need to concatenate each 20 files into a new file, so i used the following command:

```
cat part-r-0000*_dep1.csv part-r-0001*_dep1.csv > part_0-19.csv
cat part-r-0002*_dep1.csv part-r-0003*_dep1.csv > part_20-39.csv
cat part-r-0004*_dep1.csv part-r-0005*_dep1.csv > part_40-59.csv
cat part-r-0006*_dep1.csv part-r-0007*_dep1.csv > part_60-79.csv
.
.
```

However, I need to do run this command too many times to the end of the folder. Is there way to do it smarter and more efficient? I don't have a lot of experience with this operating system, so i would happy to get some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
for (( i = 0 ; i < 800 ; i += 20 )) ; do
    for (( j = i ; j < i + 20 ; ++j )) ; do
        cat "part-r-$(printf %05d "$j")_dep1.csv"
    done > "part_$i-$((i+19)).csv"
done
```

Here `i` takes the values {`0`, `20`, `40`, …, `780`} (so that you write to `part_0-19.csv`, `part_20-39.csv`, etc.), and if (for example) `i` is `20`, then `j` takes the values {`20`, `21`, … `39`} (so that you read from `part-r-00020_dep1.csv`, `part-r-00021_dep1.csv`, etc.).

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use your code and got: `Syntax error: Bad for loop variable`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Supertwister: Ah, yes. Your question is tagged as [bash], but you're probably running this from the Ubuntu interactive shell, which by default is actually Dash. (Dash doesn't have all the features that Bash does; it's optimized for speed and simplicity instead.) The simplest fix is just to open `bash`, and then run the command I provided.

Comment: Thanks. Works very well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can store all the input files in an array, then pass the names in chunks to `cat` using the substring expansion operator on the array.

```
batch_size=20

files=(part-r-*_dep1.csv)

for ((start=0; start < ${#files[@]}; start+=batch_size)); do
    cat "${files[@]:start:batch_size}" > part_${start}_$((start+batch_size-1)).csv
done
```

(This is basically the same answer as ruakh's, but they array lets you minimize the number of times you call `cat`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'e just tested your script, and got `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. Any idea why?

Comment: +1. The main difference between this approach and mine, IMHO, is that this one is driven from what the file-names actually are, whereas mine is driven from what they are expected to be. If some numbers are missing, then both approaches will blow up, but in different ways. :-P They're both useful approaches to have in one's toolkit.